# Subtract 2 cells from each and place the value in another cell which is non editable.

Tags: vba, excel

I have one worksheet which can be entered by customer. For example,

column c value should come from column B - Column A. Whenever the user enters the value in both A and B columns, it should automatically reflects the Column C.

Am using VBA code.

Thanks.

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: And what have you tried so far??

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're asking how to unprotect and then re-protect a worksheet when the user makes entries to column A and B.   You can do this, assuming the user is entering values on "Sheet1":

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(target, Me.Range("A:B")) Is Nothing Then     
      Application.EnableEvents = False
      UnprotectSheet1

      Dim row As Integer
      row = target.row

      Cells(row, 3) = Cells(row, 2) - Cells(row, 1)

      ProtectSheet1
      Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

End Sub


Public Sub UnprotectSheet1()
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="password"
End Sub


Public Sub ProtectSheet1()
  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    .Protect Password:="password"
    .EnableSelection = xlUnlockedCells
  End With
End Sub
```

This code has to go in the code section of "Sheet1"

Comment: hi thanks. yes i got it. but now my issue is : Column C should be non editable. if I locked the column then i cant able to do any changes in that column by VBA code. so, user cannot edit that column. but developer can pass the value to column c (A-B) with help of VBA code.

Comment: Sheets(SheetName).Range("H1:H100").Protect Password:=PassWord, UserInterfaceOnly:=True. I tried this code in Workbook_Open() function. its not working.

Comment: You mean Sheets(SheetName).Range("C1:C100")?  You can have a combination of unprotected and protected cells on the sheet.  The code above should work (assuming you know the password).

Comment: Hi. But i am getting another one issue. I can make the column as non editable. but whenever I close and open the excel, the column can be editable mode. why so?

Comment: Looks like you have re-protect the workbook when you first open it.  You can protect it in the Workbook_Open function in the ThisWorkbook sheet (you should see this in the project menu of the VBA editor).  You should be able to google about Workbook_Open.  This is the first thing that excel calls when the workbook is first opened.

Comment: Did you actually protect Column "C" somewhere else in the code?  I assumed you did.   If not you can protect it in workbook_open.